# error 1093: MySQL can’t specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1093

**`error 1093: MySQL can’t specify target table 'SENTIERO' for update in FROM clause`**

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER lunghezza_sentiero_datoderivato_INSERT
AFTER INSERT ON SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

UPDATE SENTIERO
SET lunghezza= (SELECT SUM(lunghezza)
                FROM TAPPA, SENTIERO as S2, SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA
                WHERE NEW.IDsentiero=S2.IDsentiero
                and SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA.IDtappa=TAPPA.IDtappa);
WHERE IDsentiero IN (SELECT IDsentiero
                     FROM TAPPA, SENTIERO, SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA
                     WHERE SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA.IDsentiero=SENTIERO.IDsentiero
                     and NEW.IDtappa=SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA.IDtappa);
END$$
```

**I've found this article** about this issue, check it on
http://verysimple.com/2011/03/30/mysql-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/

Is it the only chance i have? **Please help me**

**EDIT:: i've just added the 'WHERE' clause but it signals me "error syntax"... why?**

Comment: You get the error from the WHERE because there's an `;` immediately before it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE SENTIERO s
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT IDsentiero, TheSum
   FROM
   (
      SELECT S2.IDsentiero, SUM(s2.lunghezza) AS TheSum
      FROM SENTIERO AS S2 
      INNER JOIN SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA AS st ON st.IDsentiero = S2.IDsentiero
      INNER JOIN TAPPA             AS  t ON st.IDtappa    = t.IDtappa
      GROUP BY S2.IDsentiero
   ) AS Sub
) AS s2 ON s.IDsentiero  = s2.IDsentiero 
SET s.lunghezza = s2.TheSum
WHERE S2.IDsentiero = NEW.IDsentiero;
```

---

### Update:

You have to get the sum of the values of `lunghezza` from the `TAPPA` table not from the `SENTIERO`, thats why you were getting `NULL` values. So the final `CREATE TRIGGER` code should be like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER lunghezza_sentiero_datoderivato_INSERT
AFTER INSERT ON SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  UPDATE SENTIERO s
  INNER JOIN
  (
     SELECT IDsentiero, TheSum
     FROM
     (
        SELECT S2.IDsentiero, SUM(t.lunghezza) AS TheSum
        FROM SENTIERO AS S2 
        INNER JOIN SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA AS st ON st.IDsentiero = S2.IDsentiero
        INNER JOIN TAPPA             AS  t ON st.IDtappa    = t.IDtappa
        GROUP BY S2.IDsentiero
     ) AS Sub
  ) AS s2 ON s.IDsentiero  = s2.IDsentiero 
  SET s.lunghezza = s2.TheSum;

END
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/452a5/1)

**Note that:** This trigger will update the values of `lunghezza` in the table `SENTIERO`, when any row being inserted into the table `SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA` ***for all the `IDsentiero`*** in the `SENTIERO`, not just the value of the new inserted `IDsentiero`.

To update only the value of `lunghezza` for the new inserted value of `IDsentiero` into the table `SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA` only, add a `WHERE S2.IDsentiero = NEW.IDsentiero` to the `UPDATE` statement of the trigger. Like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER lunghezza_sentiero_datoderivato_INSERT
AFTER INSERT ON SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  UPDATE SENTIERO s
  INNER JOIN
  (
     SELECT IDsentiero, TheSum
     FROM
     (
        SELECT S2.IDsentiero, SUM(t.lunghezza) AS TheSum
        FROM SENTIERO AS S2 
        INNER JOIN SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA AS st ON st.IDsentiero = S2.IDsentiero
        INNER JOIN TAPPA             AS  t ON st.IDtappa    = t.IDtappa
        GROUP BY S2.IDsentiero
     ) AS Sub
  ) AS s2 ON s.IDsentiero  = s2.IDsentiero 
  SET s.lunghezza = s2.TheSum
  WHERE S2.IDsentiero = NEW.IDsentiero;

END;
```

For instance, if you create the three tables, then insert the data to the tables and then create that trigger. Then do an insert into the table `SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA` like this:

```
INSERT INTO `SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA` (`IDtappa`, `IDsentiero`) VALUES (14, 4);
```

Then the trigger will update the value of the `IDsentiero = 4` only in the table `SENTIERO`, not all the values of it. And the values of `lunghezza` for other `IDsentiero`'s will be `NULL`s:

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f75f4/1).

So, you have to create your tables and the triggers before any insert. Then do the insertions into the tables, so that you get a consistent data. That's how it should work.

Like in the following demo:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/543f93/1).

---

<sup>**Note that:** <sup>In all the demos in this answer, I used only the three tables involved with the trigger, also I modified the two fields `inizio`, `fine` to be nullable in the table `TAPPA`, because your insert clauses into that table have `NULL` values to those columns.</sup></sup>

Comment: what about the 'WHERE' clause?

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana This the same query as using the `IN` predicate and the `WHERE` clause that you posted in your edit. `INNER JOIN` is similar to the `IN` predicate and the condition in the `WHERE` clause is moved to the `ON` condition of the `JOIN`. Have you tried this?

Comment: i'm a beginner it's not so easy for me understand this, i'll try, but is there no chance to use 'WHERE' clause? ^^

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana Do you want to do this for every `IDsentiero` in this table? or this value `SUM(lunghezza)` will be the same?

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana If you want to update this column `lunghezza` with the same value `SUM(lunghezza)` for all the rows, then there is no need for the `WHERE` clause, and use a `SELECT` inside `SELECT`. If not, and you want to update the value `lunghezza` to be = `SUM(lunghezza)` for each grouped `IDsentiero` then you can't do this with a `WHERE` clause and the only way is to use `INNER JOIN`

Comment: i've 3 tables: **SENTIERO, SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA, TAPPA**. **SENTIERO** has got a derivated data field 'lunghezza'. TAPPA has his own 'lunghezza'.  
But **SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA** is a relationship where one record of **SENTIERO** is related to many records of **TAPPA**.   So i've to calculate 'lunghezza' in **SENTIERO** (1 'lunghezza' in **SENTIERO**= many records 'lunghezza' in **TAPPA**). **SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA** is the link between these 2 TABLES

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana Have you tried the query I posted using `JOIN` it should work fine?

Comment: ok so the INNER JOIN..
yes i've tried it, but ive got this error.

Error Code: 1052. Column 'lunghezza' in field list is ambiguous.
Maybe bacause they are called with the same name, SENTIERO.lunghezza and TAPPA.lunghezza

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana Yes, you have to qualify it with an alias like `s2.lunghezza` instead. See my edit.

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana - How the two tables `TAPPA` and `SENTIERO` are related? By which keys? In my query I assumed that they are related by the column `IDsentiero` from both the table, does the table `TAPPA` doesn't have that column `IDsentiero`??

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana OK, Sorry I fixed it see my udpated answer, and sorry for confusion. Also, I think you might need to add `WHERE S2.IDsentiero = NEW.IDsentiero` to update only those new `NEW.IDsentiero`.

Comment: TAPPA has his own IDtappa, SENTIERO has his own IDsentiero, SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA has 2 FK related to those 2 tables; so it has IDsentiero and IDtappa. Sorry for the reply time, i was checking also procedures with triggers (that i've to use)

Comment: OOOOK we're going to win... i hope it'll be the last problem:
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor and reconnect.

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana - What are you using to execute this query? Try to execute this command separately: `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` then execute your query.

Comment: it seemed it worked... nothing changed for 'lunghezza' in **SENTIERO**

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana Have you tried this for a new inserted value to that table `SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA` that the trigger is defined for it?

Comment: No, i've only created the schema, tables, and there many insert, every table of the schema has at least 4-5 records.
Does the trigger run only for NEW insert?? (so i want to say: first the dmbs do INSERT INTO, then create trigger, so it's normal SENTIERO.'lunghezza' it is blank)

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana - Note that, this update will run only when any values are inserted into `SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA` and this update run against the `SENTIERO`. So try to test this way, create the schema create the trigger insert test values. Also, please try to setup a demo in [**this site**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the three tables some sample data and the trigger explaining the issue. This will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Ok so... sql fiddle doesn't recognize my syntax, i've tried in any possible way. Anyway i tried on my workbench, first creating tables and trigger, then inserting data, but SENTIERO.lunghezza doesn't change.
HERE you can check all sql code (in SQL file), and the 3 tables-trigger-insert data for fiddlesql in HTML file.  
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ly18mj6tg4e22jc/kFEAzFqSx7

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana - Sorry for late, my apologies :( . See my edit, please. Thanks.

Comment: Finally, it works; so if i have to keep updated this 'lunghezza' in **SENTIERO**, i have also to create an **after update or delete on SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA** and an **after update on TAPPA**. And the trigger would change for some field just in the trigger for **TAPPA**. Is it correct?

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana - Yes you are right, you will need to `after update or delete on SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA` to keep those values consistent, but why `after update on TAPPA` is there any values in that table that you want to keep them updated with the other tables?

Comment: Simply beacuse, if i will update some 'lunghezza' and that field belongs to an IDtappa that is in SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA, i think 'lunghezza' in SENTIERO would be updated (i know that i would run this trigger also if that lunghezza  belongs to an IDtappa that isn't in SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA, but it's easier... )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23860/discussion-between-jimmy5nomana-and-mahmoud-gamal)